# hyperlinks in HTML Editor - Java FX

Tags: hyperlink, javafx, html-editor

I am trying to add hyperlink option in the HTML Editor provided by Java FX. I dont find the option of hyperlink-ing text in the Java FX HTML Editor ?

Can anyone please let me know how we can add this option in the editor ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a strategy that may be useful - it is focused on inserting an inline image, but should be simple to adapt to inserting a hyperlink:

http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/84159/Insert-An-Image-On-Caret-Position-JavaFX